# Show "Linked section" on the right side above "Related"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, meta, hyperlinks

Stackoverflow, Stackoverflow meta and other StackExchange sites have "Linked section" on the right side above "Related".

However it seems not visible on apple.stackexchange.com. E.g. [How to convert from evernote rich text to markdown on IPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95761/how-to-convert-from-evernote-rich-text-to-markdown-on-ipad) has a link to [Is it possible to copy 'rich text' formatting on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/is-it-possible-to-copy-rich-text-formatting-on-iphone), but no "Linked section".

Don't be different, please show it.

Comment: I don't think we're different. I see a Linked Section in my view of that question you linked to. See: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/jho6rKI)

Comment: @IanC, I can see it now, but it wasn't visible  10 minutes later after the question was submitted. It seems that   delay in populating "linked" section is essential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that detects and draws the linked section executes a bit after a post is submitted, so you may not see that field immediately upon posting a new question or submitting an edit to a question/answer.

The posts you have indicated all have a linked section at present, so perhaps you had a cached copy of those pages or viewed them before the code to assemble the links had been triggered or had finished executing?